# Wrong ED50 with Dose Response Model using DRM

Tags: r, drc

When fitting a drm model to my dose response data the obtained `ED50` is off

`log(ED50)`, `log2(ED50)`, `log10(ED50)`

```
# here is some actual data
test_response <- c(0,1.130912987,-2.0159852,6.158574058,5.679161469,12.97,20.46711451,35.55009039,66.31837697)

test_dose <- c(0,0.006103516,0.024414063,0.09765625,0.39,1.5625,6.25,25,100)
test_df <- data.frame(dose=test_dose, response=test_response)

# fitting a Hill formula 
m1 <- drm(response ~ dose, data=test_df, fct=LL.4())

# optaining ED50
ED(m1, 50)
```

I get an estimated `ED50` of `1649`. When I fit the same data in a proprietary program I get a similar plot but with an (correct) `EC50` of `45.5`
I tried log10 as well as `log2` of the calculated `ED50` but it's off anyways

**Solution**

So I figured it out, the models were correct, but apparently there's when using `ED()` one can choose between `type="absolute"` and `type="relative"` where "relative" ist the default; in my case given those response values are absolute, changing this parameter gave me the right `ED50s`

Comment: you must convert `test_response` to percentage (0% to 100%). ED50  is a concentration that 50% of `test_response` is observed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but actually, this doesn't solve my problem. Of note, when I use predict() to reverse predict the dose with a 50% response I can approximae the correct dose for the EC50, which, in this case, should be around 28